# Selenium + Python 3.x recaptcha как отправить ответ капче и можно ли это сделать через get

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, recaptcha, captcha

На сайте есть капча, с сервиса я получаю ответ и должен его отправить в капчу я знаю что можно просто поменять код вместо display: none; поставить display: block; и ввести туда ответ, но можно-ли сделать так чтобы моя программа отправила ответ капче и капча автоматически проверила ответ можно-ли так сделать?

Comment: возможный [дубликат вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1230408/420098)?